# Emergency insurance without clear residence of a country

Tags: usa, canada, eu-citizens, europe, insurance

I am German citizen (having official secondary residence there, I.e. an address) but haven’t lived there for ten years (no job and insurance). This is where I physically reside at the very moment.

But currently I am a *temporary* resident (temporary worker) in Canada (for 2-3 more weeks).

In two months I WILL become permanent resident of the US and start a job there.

Now I am looking for an emergency insurance for this gap of 2 months that includes moving (and change of my primary residence status).

But believe it or not, upon close inspection is is non trivial. Travel insurance is not the right thing because it’s technically not travel. Digital Nomad insurance still requires a “home country” (which of the three would it be??).

Which option(s) do I have?

Comment: Are there reasons (legal, financial, fiscal) that you can't reestablish your residence in Germany?

Comment: In general no, but: 1) it's just for a gap of 1 month 2) i don't have any insurance/social insurance there whatsoever. Its been 10 years that I left Germany.